# c++ set a cursor using SetCursor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, cursor

ok im setting a cursor in a loop it works but when i move the cursor it just changes back to the way it was. im using win32 api and i used 

`SetCursor(LoadCursor(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_PROTECTED)));`

any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, you want to call `SetCursor` in response to `WM_SETCURSOR`. If memory serves, the cursor will also stay what you've set if the cursor member of the window class is set to NULL.

Comment: Tried which -- setting the class cursor to NULL, or calling `SetCursor` in response to `WM_SETCURSOR`? In the latter case, you also need to return `TRUE` from the message handler. I just did a quick check of responding to `WM_SETCURSOR` and it worked quite nicely.

Comment: when i register the window i have set it to my cursor but when it runs i see an hour glass cursor than when i set it to my other cursor it works. if i take out the WM_CURSOR the first cursor works but the second doesn't stay

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is being changed by DefWindowProc().

if you want a different cursor over your window, use SetClassLong(), or, change the hCursor field of WNDCLASS when calling RegisterClass, if you are the one who's calling it youself

Comment: im changing the cursor not when program starts when an event happenes

Comment: @Ramiz: How does that contradict the suggestion to call SetClassLong() ? (Actually, you want `SetClassLongPtr(GCLP_HCURSOR)` for 64 bits compat, but that's a detail)

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try setcursor in WM_MOUSEMOVE.

Comment: Very bad suggestion in terms of efficiency (laptop battery power, etc).